# TechSupport Issue ID#812

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking, story

User ID: 3Aq47h-20dpc8l

Language: English (UK)

---

Today I noticed a strange text file on my Windows 10 PC's Desktop called "README.txt". Curious, I opened it and it read

> START → 2↑ → P  3→ ↑ P 4→ P → P 2↓ ← P 4← 2↑ P → ↓ P 5← P ↑ 4→ 2P 3→ P 5← 2↓ P 5→ ↑ P → P 6← ↑ P ← ↓ P

My computer has been freaking me out, I've been paranoid for days now, I think my computer is possessed! Can you please help me!

Comment: A nice quick puzzle for you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It says

> STOP.THATTICKLES.

or, if you prefer,

> "Stop. That tickles."

so I guess

> your keyboard would like you to change the way you type. (And yes, maybe it is indeed possessed.)

Explanation:

> if you start on the "Windows" key on your keyboard -- the one that produces the "start menu" -- and then make the motions described by the arrows, entering a character at each P, that's what you get.